# How to convert webcam image to RGB Depth

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm building an iPhone-like FaceID program using my PC's webcam. I'm following [this notebook](https://github.com/normandipalo/faceID_beta/blob/master/faceid_beta.ipynb) which uses Kinect to create RGB-D images. So can I use my webcam to capture several images for the same purpose?

Here's how to predict the person in the Kinect image. It uses a .dat file.

```
inp1 = create_input_rgbd(file1)
file1 = ('faceid_train/(2012-05-16)(154211)/011_1_d.dat')
inp2 = create_input_rgbd(file1)

model_final.predict([inp1, inp2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use  Kinect to create RGB-D images where you want to only use RGB camera to do the similar? Hardwarely they are different. So there wont be a direct method

You have to first estimate a depth map using only monocular Image.

Well you can try with Revisiting Single Image Depth Estimation: Toward Higher Resolution Maps with Accurate Object Boundaries as shown below. The depth obtained is pretty much close to real ground truth. For non-life threatening case(e.g control UAV or control car), you can use it anytime.

[image]

The code and model are available at

https://github.com/JunjH/Revisiting_Single_Depth_Estimation

**Edit the demo py file to do a single image detection.**

```
    image = you
    deep_learned_fake_depth = model(image)
    #Add your additional classification routing behind.
```

Take note this method cant work real time. So you can only do it at keyframes. Usualy people use the feature tracking technique to fake continuous detection( which is the common practice).

Also take note that some of the phone devices does have a small depth estimation sensor that you can make use of. Details I'm not very sure as I deal android and ios at a very minimal level.